# Can Ultrasound be a possible solution to treat COVID-19 virus?

Tags: covid-19, ultrasounds

An article from 2008: [New way to kill virus: Shake them to death](https://www.livescience.com/7472-kill-viruses-shake-death.html).
Can ultrasound have the potential to treat COVID-19 infected humans at large-scale (because it does not require anesthesia)?

I went through an answer on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Are-ultrasonic-waves-harmful-to-the-human-body). Is it a good idea to make a cavity with ultrasound for humans, specifically targeting the respiratory organs?

My apologies if this seems dope, I myself am an engineer, but this COVID-19 seems to affect the future generations as well so I thought of asking here. Please validate it.

References:
[Effects of ultrasound on living organisms](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=AXArBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=whitewater%20electronics%20ultrasound&source=bl&ots=b5ehLFwUBM&sig=ACfU3U2EiR92YBGO77GV4mcU11_6hIEVwg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwierYfI0rnoAhXvxzgGHa2NCywQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=whitewater%20electronics%20ultrasound&f=false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[High intensity focused ultrasound][1] can be quite targeted and get into deep parts of the body, including into the brain. But while it would likely kill the virus, I don't think it's very realistic to be sonicating everywhere the virus might be, because it isn't very localized. You can't use FUS on the entire lung, as that would cause far too much damage if you were to have any impact on reducing viral load. This is just my opinion, but I do think that a good antiviral treatment for SARS COV 2 will need systemic effects, not localized.

Comment: US has only been used on blood so there's no data to show that you can use a resonant frequency to affect virus and not tissues.

Comment: According to this site, https://radiopaedia.org/articles/ultrasound-frequencies
Ultrasound of MHz order is used for the purpose of imaging, which cannot have any side effects. Whereas, for the inactivation of Viruses, we need the US in the order of kHz (https://aem.asm.org/content/aem/57/7/2079.full.pdf). Even bats produce sounds in the kHz order, they don`t affect humans.
Please validate.

Comment: Please check this. https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/article/ultrasound-treatment-kills-cancer-cells

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like science fiction and not much use for treating patients.  They talk about shining laser light on the virus to induce the resonant frequency to shatter the virus.

But, Covid-19 is a deep tissue infection,  and I can't imagine how lasers could possibly get inside the lung, heart and other tissues affected by this virus.